# Do we know anything about the decision making involved with for example Jaguar Land Rover security system?

Tags: security, automotive-design

It has been in the news for a few years that Jaguar Land Rover (JLR) cars are being stolen via exploits in the wireless security system.  [The most recent story](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-68188064) is that JLR are denying they are the worst without denying that there is a issue, indicating that this problem is fairly widespread.

Has JLR or any affected car company commented about how such a security vulnerability made it into so many cars?  Presumably every car company had some security expert review the system during the design phase.  Do we know what any of these reviews found?

Comment: I expect you'll get better answers on https://security.stackexchange.com, I've seen similar questions there. As a security professional I've shaken my head as car companies have ignored basic principles and good security practice, they seem to do little independent testing as most of what I've seen is independent researchers. I haven't been paying attention to JLR though.